# Периодически у Laravel 6 появляются ошибки соединения с redis

Tags: php, laravel, redis

Не могу понять почему теряется связь с redis и сайт становиться не доступен, помогает только /etc/init.d/php7.3-fpm restart

в php-slow.log начинает сыпется эти ошибки и наверное забивают все php процессы.

```
script_filename = /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/public/index.php
[0x00007fc7f001f880] set() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php:116
[0x00007fc7f001f7c0] command() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/PhpRedisConnection.php:519
[0x00007fc7f001f720] command() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/PhpRedisConnection.php:85
[0x00007fc7f001f650] set() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php:171
[0x00007fc7f001f5c0] forever() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php:355
[0x00007fc7f001f510] forever() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheManager.php:378
[0x00007fc7f001f470] __call() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:261
```

на сервере стоит php 7.3.14 Redis 5.0.3 и phpredis 5.3.1 недавно обновил думал дело в phpredis.
Пробовал использовать predis так же бывает теряет связь.

```
script_filename = /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/public/index.php
[0x00007f691ea20b60] fgets() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php:311
[0x00007f691ea20a30] read() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:120
[0x00007f691ea209c0] readResponse() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:112
[0x00007f691ea20950] executeCommand() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php:331
[0x00007f691ea208d0] executeCommand() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php:314
[0x00007f691ea20840] __call() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php:116
[0x00007f691ea20780] command() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php:220
[0x00007f691ea206f0] __call() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php:54
[0x00007f691ea20660] get() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/TagSet.php:87
[0x00007f691ea205e0] tagId() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/TagSet.php:76
[0x00007f691ea20570] array_map() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/TagSet.php:76
[0x00007f691ea20500] tagIds() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/TagSet.php:66
[0x00007f691ea20430] getNamespace() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisTaggedCache.php:34
[0x00007f691ea20330] put() /home/admin/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php:383
```

redis работает на одном сервере с php, сам redis настроен на работу через unix socket.

В логах redis пусто.